# detect repeated word c++, doesn't detect the first word

Tags: c++

This is some code I'm practicing from *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++*:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int numberOfWords = 0;

    string previous = " ";  // the operator >> skips white space

    string current;

    cout << "Type some stuff.";

    cin >> current;

    while (cin >> current) {

        ++numberOfWords;    // increase word count

        if (previous == current)

            cout << "word number " << numberOfWords

                 << " repeated: " << current << '\n';

        previous = current;


    }

}
```

It is working just as intended, but I noticed that it does not detect a repeated *first* word - for instance "run run" will have no return and "run run run" will tell me I repeated word number 2 but not word number 1. Just out of curiosity, what would I need to change in this code to detect if word 1 is repeated?

Answer (score 1):

With this you are skipping the first word:

```
cin >> current;

while (cin >> current) {
```

Edit: As first word cannot be compared to anything , we can set value of first word to previous and start comparing from second word:

```
cin >> previous;
while (cin >> current) {
```

Comment: What would you recommend as the most efficient way of changing this to include the first word?

Answer (score 0):

Just code exactly what you want. Here's one way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numberOfWords = 1;
    bool previousMatch = false;

    string previous;  // the operator >> skips white space
    string current;

    cout << "Type some stuff." << std::endl;

    cin >> previous;
    while (cin >> current)
    {
        if (previous == current)
        {
            if (! previousMatch)
            {   // Previous word repeated too
                cout << "word number " << numberOfWords
                     << " repeated: " << current << '\n';
                previousMatch = true;
            }

            cout << "word number " << numberOfWords + 1
                 << " repeated: " << current << '\n';
        }
        else
            previousMatch = false;

        ++numberOfWords;    // increase word count
        previous = current;
    }
}
```